# NSDictionary error. How to solve it?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I use touchjson library. I receive json structure.

1. `{"My dishes": ""}` if i have not my dishes or
2. `{"My dishes": [{"dish": "rice with fish""restaurant_id": "35", "latitude": "39.783871","longitude": "-96.314759"}]}` if i have a dish.

-

```
NSDictionary *all_dish = [dictionary objectForKey:@"My dishes"];
for (NSDictionary *my_dish in all_dish) {
  //some code
}
```

in the first case , i get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2900688'
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there a way you could receive `{"My dishes": []}` instead of `{"My dishes": ""}`? It would work in both cases.

Comment: Ok, i will try to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case the object for key `My dishes` is not a dictionary, but a `NSString`, which does not support fast enumeration.

In the second case, `all_dishes` isn't a `NSDictionary` but a `NSArray`. I am surprised it works.

The way no dishes is handled is broken from where I stand: if you have no dishes `My dishes` should have a value of `null` or an empty list, not "".

If you can't control this, check whether the value of `My dishes` is an `NSArray` before attempting to enumerate over it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([allDish isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *my_dish in all_dish) {
        if ([myDish isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```